# MAMP vs MAMP PRO security - newbie

Tags: security, localhost, mamp

I’m thinking of upgrading to MAMP PRO from MAMP because I’m uncomfortable setting up virtual hosts myself. At the same time I’m reluctant to do anything that could compromise the security of my computer.

I’ve noticed in the MAMP PRO documentation the warning ‘for security reasons it is recommended to run the servers as www/mysql when your Mac is connected to the internet.’ Seeing as this configuration option isn’t available for MAMP can anyone please explain which user account the server runs on when you only use the free version.

Any advice on which version would be safer to use for someone that is new to this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you have this option only on MAMP PRO. on MAMP, the "free" version, you do not have this possibility.

Note: If you do not enable this on MAMP PRO, you also stay "safe"